# Flutter Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, boolean, var

```
class _FiltersScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {
  var _glutenFree = false;
  var _vegetarian = false;
  var _vegan = false;
  var _lactoseFree = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    _glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'];         ----> ERROR
    _lactoseFree = widget.currentFilters['lactose'];       ----> ERROR
    _vegetarian = widget.currentFilters['vegetarian'];     ----> ERROR
    _vegan = widget.currentFilters['vegan'];               ----> ERROR
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _buildSwitchListTile(
    String title,
    String description,
    bool currentValue,
    Function updateValue,
  ) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: currentValue,
      subtitle: Text(
        description,
      ),
      onChanged: updateValue,       ------> ERROR
    );
  }
```

I am not a Flutter pro.
I have no idea, I also tried bool instead of var. Can you help me?
I have marked the Errors in the lines. Thank You!

Comment: take a look on [Null Safety in Dart](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is much better to post the error messages exactly as they appear on your end here, in addition to the lines they appear in.

Answer (score 0):

The response may have null values.

Either try assigning your bools with their type :

```dart
bool? _glutenFree = false;
bool? _vegetarian = false;
bool? _vegan = false;
bool? _lactoseFree = false;
```

Or :

```dart
_glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'] ?? false;
_lactoseFree = widget.currentFilters['lactose'] ?? false;
_vegetarian = widget.currentFilters['vegetarian'] ?? false;
_vegan = widget.currentFilters['vegan'] ?? false;
```

Also, the `updateValue` function is of type `ValueChanged<bool>`, so when assigning the new value make sure they are of the same type.

Comment: Tank you for your help, but this is also not working :/

Comment: If I use bool? 
-> then I get here an error:

Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildSwitchListTile(
                  'Gluten-free',
                  'Only include gluten-free meals.',
                  _glutenFree,                                        ----> ERROR
                  (newValue) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        _glutenFree = newValue;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),

Comment: Yes that's because `value` of `SwitchListTile` is of type `bool` not `bool?`. Try addiing a`null` check like `_gluttenFree ?? false`. AND the `newValue` is of type `bool`

Comment: the error ist gone, but my emulator is still not working

Comment: `flutter clean && flutter pub get` and rebuild.

Comment: i hav still a red screen

Comment: could it be another mistake?

Comment: No error message ?

Comment: no error message

Comment: how can I clean and pub get?

Comment: Stop the running project and type the commands on your IDE terminal.

Comment: Ok, I did
But still a red screen

Comment: Can't help without an error message though.

Comment: or can we communicate differently?
can i send you my code?